# Using enum value as a type in Interface in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

Is below a valid use of an enum in an interface?

```
declare enum MyEnumType {
   Member1,
   Member2,
}
```

```
interface Foo {
  prop1: MyEnumType,          // this is valid
  prop2: MyEnumType.Member1   // how about this? If not, why?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this code in a sandbox, you will get an Error:

```
Enum type 'MyEnumType' has members with initializers that are not literals.
```

It is invalid only if you `declare` the enum. In this case you tell TS that enum exists, but you don't tell it what are it's values, because the definition of this enum could be like this:

```
enum MyEnumType {
  Member1 = 8,
  Member2 = 'RaNdOmWhAtEvEr'
}
```

This means `MyEnumType.Member2` is ambiguous. It will works if you

1. Define enum explicitly (remove `declare` keyword). Now TypeScript is in full control of the enum and it knows it will assign values `0` and `1` to its keys
2. Explicitly tell, what are the keys of the declared enum

```
declare enum MyEnumType {
  Member1 = 0,
  Member2 = 1
}
```

Now TS knows what to expect from the enum and is able to operate with its keys as types.